# Exclude a folder in a script that checks for file changes?

Tags: file, cron, cron-task

I have a cronjob that runs every 24 hours to tell me if files on my server have changed. The script is as such:

```
find /home/bsc1933 -type f -ctime -1 -exec ls -ls {} \; | mail -E -s “File Changes, Past 24 Hours” myemail
```

I would like to modify it to exclude a specific folder, in this case my cache folder: `/home/bsc1933/public_html/cache`

I found the original script with Google-fu and just edited the email to match mine, so my knowledge of actually editing the script itself is non-existent. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `grep` or `find` to ignore entries with a certain pattern.

With grep:

```
find /home/bsc1933 -type f -ctime -1 -exec ls -ls {} \; |grep -Ev  "/home/bsc1933/public_html/cache" | mail -E -s “File Changes, Past 24 Hours” myemail
```

Or telling find to ignore it:

```
find /home/bsc1933 ! -path '*/.cache/*' -type f -ctime -1 -exec ls -ls {} \; | mail -E -s “File Changes, Past 24 Hours” myemail
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is as follows, by adding "grep" to filter out path you wish to exclude, between "find" and "mail" command.

```
`find /home/bsc1933 -type f -ctime -1 -exec ls -ls {} \; | grep -v '/home/bsc1933/public_html/cache' |` ... your code to send email ...
```

Let me know if you face any other difficulties.